# power BI relative date filter

Tags: powerbi

Relative Date Functionality in Power BI:

**Issue #1:**
Hi Team,

Need to know is there any way to implement the below relative date filter functionality in Power BI

[image]

Please note the following:

For year the base year should be current year, for now it should be 2021

For month the base month should be current month, for now it should be july and so on.

**Issue#2:**

Based on the above, we want to implement a functionality based on the below selection, where in if we select week, then we should see the count of a metric only for the weeks which are passed by the above filters and similarly for months, days etc. For eg, if we select year, then we should get the count for the year 2022 only as this is the only year passed by the above filter.

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Technically possible? I think so. Feasible? No, not really.

While there is some playroom with bookmarks, custom graphics and clever use of a wide range of measures and calculation groups - it would be an enormous task to get everything running correctly and smoothly.

Perhaps one option is to introduce this filtering functionality via a custom visual that takes your date column as input?